# When to use the Jacobian in the change of variables formula

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, jacobian

I have a really hard time understanding when to use the Jacobian (in the change of variables formula) when I'm calculating integrals. Every time I think I get it I always stumble upon a case when I shouldn't use it. It seems rather arbitrary, for example:

I'm looking at the definition/derivation of the surface integral of the vector field $F$ on the area $T$: 
$$\int\int_T(F\cdot n)dS$$
$T$ parametrized with $r(s,t)$ with the domain $D$. With
$$n = \frac{r'_s \times r'_t}{|r'_s \times r'_t|},$$
$$dS = |r'_s \times r'_t|dsdt$$
We get:
$$\int\int_T(F\cdot n)dS = \int\int_DF(r(s,t))\cdot \frac{r'_s \times r'_t}{|r'_s \times r'_t|}\cdot|r'_s \times r'_t|dsdt$$
Which nets 
$$\int\int_DF(r(s,t))\cdot (r'_s \times r'_t)dsdt$$

**My question is**: Why aren't we using the jacobian according to the change of variable formula to compensate  when going from the domain $T$ to $D$?

Comment: Can you tell us how exactly do you want the Jacobian? Just add your alternative approach with Jacobian too so we can see what you mean better and explain why (if at all) your second method is problematic.

Comment: This isn't a change of variables in an ordinary double integral; it's the definition of the flow integral $\iint_T$ in terms of the ordinary double integral $\iint_D$. So there's no reason to expect anything like the usual change-of-variables formula.